# How to remap physical keyboard, or to change Android OS to another language

Tags: keyboard, android

Hello all
I have a Desire Z Android 2.2 English with psysical keyboard.
I need to have three local characters on the physical keyboard.
I can certainly access them via longpress and choose on touch screen but it kills the flow when texting and writing email.
1. Can I change Android OS from English to another language in the next update?
2. If not, can I modify the file data in the system, so that I remap three unused keys to what I want to have?
3. Do you have any other way to go about it?
Kind rgds

Comment: Perhaps this would be better on android.se?

Answer (score 0):

1. Apparently you can (haven't tried it):
   [Change language programmatically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-language-programatically-in-android)
2. You can not modify file on a file system, except your own files. Ever app is installed under a separate username, and privileges are set so that one app has no privileges to access other app or system files.
3. Not that I know. Option 1. seems to be the way.

Beware: personally I wouldn't want an app to remap my keyboard. This is something that only user should do.